# redirect a call using cisco tcl ivr

Tags: tcl, cisco, ivr

I have this scenario in my mind:

A user call is connected to support line, if the support team will not pick up within 30 seconds, the call will be forwarded to another number which is a voice mail.

I have tried consultation mode with no success, because I get unsupported error. Now I am trying the simple recommended scenario using leg Setup and call info.

In a nutshell, I have placed a call and support team is already ringing, nobody picks up and 30 seconds is passed, now I want to redirect the call using the following commands:

```
set VoiceMail 7777

set callInfo(alertTime) 40 

set callInfo(originationNum) 83382992 

set callInfo(mode)        "ROTARY"

set callInfo(rerouteMode) "REDIRECT_ROTARY"

leg setup $VoiceMail callInfo leg_incoming
```

but when run, this returns an error stating "CallSetup already active on leg"

any help on that? if I disconnect the leg using "leg disconnect leg_incoming" the call is closed (I think)

Thanks